# Cucumber and capybara scenario session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cucumber, capybara

I did a lot of R&D and still have no answer for simple question - where is my session object?

I have a scenario like this:

```
Scenario: I should be able to add products to the basket
  Given I have a product named "Mousepad" # creates object using FactoryGirl
  When I add "Mousepad" to basket         # sends POST request to add product 
  Then I should have 1 item in my basket  # visit basket page
```

Here's basket method:

```
def set_current_basket
  @basket = (session[:basket] ||= Basket.new)
end
```

It works fine in browser, but not in tests. @basket allways is new object. 
Even if I set session[:test] = 1 in the first step, it will be nil in the next one.

Did I miss something, how does it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind Capybara is that you will emulate the user behavior, for that reason you shouldn't need direct session access.

However I agree that this is not true 100% of the time, specially when you rely on some third part software, in that case I recommend the gem [rack_session_access](https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access), it will allow you to access you session like that:

```
page.set_rack_session basket: Basket.new
```

and access it by `page.get_rack_session_key('basket')`

Please keep in mind that this is a hack and you shouldn't need direct access to your session if your final user does not need it too.

Comment: Okay, so what is a **right** way to test checkout process using Cucumber and Capybara? I can't find it.

Comment: You should base your assertions on something that the final user would use. For instance, instead of checking the session you could check if, after the checkout process, a success message would be displayed. You can answer yourself such question by wondering: "How does my end user knows that his checkout worked?".